# El valor del tipo especificado Guid del origen de datos no se puede convertir al tipo varchar de la columna de destino especificada

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Estoy realizando una funcionalidad donde ocupo dos BulkCopy para procesar datos a una BD, en la BD creo una tabla con 2 columnas una es CDSN VARCHAR(100), InventarioClave VARCHAR(200), en mi primer Bulk proceso un archivo txt el cual contiene una sola columna que se va a volcar en la columna CDSN de la BD y la otra columna queda nula.

Una vez que se hace ese BulkCopy, tomo los valores como parametro para hacer otra consulta y al obtener los resultados los agrego a un datatable, con ese segundo datatable hago otro BulkCopy pero al procesar este Bulk me genera un error en dt2

> El valor del tipo especificado Guid del origen de datos no se puede convertir al tipo varchar de la columna de destino especificada.

Mi codigo

```html
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
                dt = (CargarDatos(txtPath, ',', true));

                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("***"))
                {
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand("IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ReporteAQuery', 'u') IS NOT NULL   DROP TABLE[dbo].[ReporteQuery]; ; CREATE TABLE  ReporteQuery([CDSN] VARCHAR(100),[InventarioClave] VARCHAR(200))", conn))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
                            {
                                bulkcopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 6600;
                                bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "ReporteQuery";
                                bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CDSN", "CDSN");
                                bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                                bulkcopy.Close();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (IOException ex)
                        {
                            // Handle exception properly
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                using (SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection("***"))
                {
                    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("MyTable2");
                    dt2 = DtInventarioClv();

                    using (var command1 = new SqlCommand("IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ReporteQuery', 'u') IS NOT NULL   DROP TABLE[dbo].[ReporteQuery]; ; CREATE TABLE  ReporteQuery([CDSN] VARCHAR(100),[InventarioClave] VARCHAR(200))", conn2))
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            conn2.Open();
                            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopyX = new SqlBulkCopy(conn2))
                            {
                                bulkcopyX.BulkCopyTimeout = 6600;
                                bulkcopyX.DestinationTableName = "ReporteQuery";
                                bulkcopyX.ColumnMappings.Add("CDSN", "CDSN");
                                bulkcopyX.ColumnMappings.Add("InventarioClave", "InventarioClave");
                                bulkcopyX.WriteToServer(dt2);
                                bulkcopyX.Close();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (IOException ex)
                        {
                            // Handle exception properly
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            conn2.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Funciones DataTables

```html
        public static DataTable CargarDatos(string rutaArchivo, char separadorArchivos, bool firstLine)
        {
            DataTable dt = null;
            string[] encabezados;
            string[] lineaActual;
            //using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(rutaArchivo)))
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(rutaArchivo))
            {
                string linea;

                List<string> lineas = new List<string>();
                //Lee el archivo de texto linea a linea
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    linea = sr.ReadLine();
                    lineas.Add(linea);
                }

                dt = new DataTable();

                if (firstLine)
                {
                    encabezados = lineas[0].Split(Convert.ToChar(separadorArchivos));
                    foreach (string col in encabezados)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(col);
                    }
                }

                for (int p = 1; p < lineas.Count; p++)
                {
                    lineaActual = lineas[p].Split(Convert.ToChar(separadorArchivos));
                    if (lineaActual.Length == dt.Columns.Count)
                    {
                        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                        row.ItemArray = lineaActual;
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("El numero de datos de la fila " + p + " no corresponde al numero de columnas");
                    }
                }

                sr.Close();

            }
            //File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(rutaArchivo));
            File.Delete(rutaArchivo);
            return dt;
        }
```

```
 public DataTable DtInventarioClv()
    {
        DataTable dt;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("***");
        con.Open();

        string consulta = "SELECT B.NumeroSerie AS CDSN,B.InventarioClave FROM Apoyo.dbo.ReporteQuery A INNER JOIN vw_inventario B ON B.NumeroSerie=A.CDSN ";

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(consulta, con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
        da.Dispose();

        return dt;
    }
```

Error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizá no lo he entendido del todo, pero ¿porqué haces un drop table en el segundo using para hacer el segundo bulkcopy? No se supone que esa tabla la acabas de crear y llenar con los datos leidos del txt. Si te la cargas, ¿cuál es el sentido? `using (var command1 = new SqlCommand("IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ReporteQuery', 'u') IS NOT NULL   DROP TABLE[dbo].[ReporteQuery]; ; CREATE TABLE  ReporteQuery([CDSN] VARCHAR(100),[InventarioClave] VARCHAR(200))", conn2))`

Comment: @Javifer2 el drop table lo coloque para generar desde 0  la tabla otra vez pensando que  al volver a llenar la tabla  con el segundo BulkCopy tenia problemas con algún identificador , pero no es asi me sigue dando el mismo error en el dt2

Comment: Hay dos cosas extrañas. Sql server no tiene GUID, que es el error que te devuelve. Por alguna razón estás leyendo los datos en un dataTabla cuyas columnas, entiende al menos una de ellas que es un guid (en sql son uniqueIdentifier), porque la definición de la tabla, es `varchar`. Si pones un punto de interrupción, antes de hacer el bulkCopy el dt, tiene que tener una columna de tipo guid. Si viene porque los datos, son en función del contenido, puedes meter una linea adicional con un texto (la primera). Otra prueba, es cambiar la definicion de la tabla, para la columna como uniqueidentifier

Comment: @Javifer2 quizá sea que mi query del  datatable DtInventarioClv me regresa en una columna información parecida a un GUID y se esta confundiendo el c# o sql server no?

Comment: Es muy probable. Sobre todo porque SQL no sabe lo que es Guid, Aunque sea quien le de la vuelta. Pero si creas la columna como Uniqueidentifier, seguro que se lo come. Siempre y cuando tenga toda la información. Otra manera, es crear las columnas del dataTable a mano. `new DataColumn("col1", typeOf(string))`

Comment: @Javifer2 para agregar columnas al datatable de forma manual en donde tengo la query que llena el dt2 le agrego             DataTable dt;
            dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn colString = new DataColumn("CDSNXX", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(colString);
            DataColumn colString2 = new DataColumn("InventarioClave", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(colString2);

Comment: @Javifer2 pero me toma el nombre de los campos que tengo en el Select y no las columnas que le agrego al datatable

Comment: Si claro, los nombres de las columnas los defines en la query del Sql, Pero el tipo de dato, que tiene el dataTable, que es lo que le va a pasar bulkInsert a Sql, los defines en el dataTable. A ese nivel, le da lo mismo. Solo le importa el tipo y la posición.

Comment: @Javifer2 Gracias por tu ayuda ya solucione el problema y ya inserto  en BD